SwiftData methods (.insert) called inside a class using SwiftUI
SwiftUI project trying to use SwiftData inside a Class vs. a View since the Class is where the data is generated (i.e. startDeviceMotionUpdates {...}.
I get error:

Referencing instance method 'modelContext' on 'Optional' requires that 'DeviceMotionManager' conform to 'View'

If I do: modelContext.insert in view it is ok but it needs to be done at the class per how the data is generated.
Is is not possible to use model insert, delete, etc. inside a class?  Thanks for any help.
I created a @Model class:
@Model
class TestData {
    var id: UUID
    var value: Float

Setup app file:
@Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
    }
    .modelContainer(for: TestData.self)
} 

Inherited the Model class (TestData) into the functional class:
@Observable 
class DeviceMotionManager : TestData {

inside this class I do motion updates to main thread: (not complete code sniptet)
startDeviceMotionUpdates {....
            let test = TestData (id: UUID(), value: self!.userAccelX )
            modelContext.insert(test).  <<-  ERROR (Referencing instance method 'modelContext' on 'Optional' requires that 'DeviceMotionManager' conform to 'View'


In your last code snippet, where does modelContext come from?

Oh wait, I just spotted a big issue. You can't use inheritance like this, as a matter of fact SwiftData doesn't support inheritance at all so remove : TestData from the declaration of DeviceMotionManager

OK thanks! - removed : TestData.   I have modelContext declared at the app level: @main
struct Accel2App: App {
@Environment(.modelContext) var modelContext

That's not right either, no need for that in @main.  How do you inject it into DeviceMotionManager? You can't use @Environment outside of a view, you know that?

I'm going to abandon the goal of using SwiftData as it seems only intended for user operations and not 'background' data collection (e.g. collect motion data).  thanks for your help - if you know how to easily use SD to insert data via a class method I would always appreciate that :)

@ModelActor is a macro for a SwiftData specific actor.
